# C# string size in working memory

Tags: .net, string, memory-management, hashset

**Situation :**

On a 64x .NET build I store approx 50 million string in a Hashset and my RAM goes from 1.5Gb to 7.5Gb .

**2 Questions :**

Looking at the 6 Gb (7.5-1.5) RAM taken by the strings ... I am correct if I state that :

> 1. Hashset object size = 8 bytes * number of strings ... and the rest up to the 6GB taken are the actual strings saved in RAM ?
> 2. If yes , if I would be to save it in the DB and use Hibernate for
>    example (with the same RAM) I will store more strings in the hashset
>    object but I will need to take in to account the R/W DB overhead ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 64 bits = 8 bytes per item in Hashset?

Comment: What does "my RAM" mean? Private working set?

Comment: My laptop RAM has 8Gb. Before I run the solution is at about 1.5 and it gradually increases while the strings are computed and added

Comment: That's not very helpful. Can you check the private working set size in task manager? Introduce some memory pressure?

Comment: RAM doesn't have much to do with memory usage. It's just a large cache for the swap (page) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. There's a bit more to the book-keeping of an object than just the size of a pointer. The object header is somewhere between 12-24 bytes (I'm not sure which is it on 64-bit - it's defined, but I don't have the time to search for the exact value right now :)). The length of the string is another 4-8 bytes. Another 4 bytes for the cached hash. Each character is *at least* two bytes. Given that out of 50 million objects, you get a memory size of 6 GiB, you get about 128 bytes per object on average. That means somewhere between 46-54 characters per string (including a two-byte null terminator). And I'm most likely forgetting other sources of overhead too.

The hashset overhead will also be larger than just the references, but probably not enough to matter.

Instead of asking on the internet, why not run a memory profiler? It will show you a nice allocation tree that will make this a certainty (on your particular configuration), rather than a guessing game.

As for other solutions, if you need the stuff in memory, there's not a whole lot of space you can gain. Maybe, if your data is all in ASCII, you could avoid using Unicode. Unless your strings are very short, that's really the only thing that would make a noticeable difference. But we really can't tell - we have no idea what your data is made of. Perhaps in-memory compressed strings will work great? We can't know - you need to test it yourself.

**EDIT:**

Since the data you want to store are just a couple of numbers, `string` is a needless waste of memory and performance overall. You can do everything with no indirection, and using just value types.

Now, if you are familiar with unsafe code, fixed buffers can make this really simple and easy to use:

```
public unsafe struct SevenNumbers
{
  public fixed ushort Numbers[7];
}
```

(don't forget to add the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` overrides)

Make sure to use a generic hashset - if you need to cast the struct to an `object`, you lose all the benefits of using a value type, and you'll pay for the references, indirection, object headers... a needless waste.

Unsafe code is commonly used for optimisations like this, but if you're not familiar/comfortable with unsafe code, you can do the same thing with a bit more code. Either you'll have to access the numbers as separate fields (`Number1`, `Number2`, ...), or you'll have to use a custom indexer to pretend the separate fields are really an array:

```
public ushort this[int index]
{
  get
  {
    if (index < 0 || index > 7) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

    switch (index)
    {
      case 0: return Number1;
      case 1: return Number2;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

In both cases, your ~100 bytes of string got turned into just 14 bytes - not bad :) If you want to press this further, you can do a bit of bit packing, and turn this even lower, to just 10 bytes (since you need at most 11 bits for each number) - but that's most likely an overkill, and the code to handle bit packing is a lot more complicated (and error-prone :)).

Comment: Example string : 900.900.900.900.900.1000.1900. Only digits and a dot ( I can replace the dot with anything). Any idea (on top of you're head) that can reduce the size in my case ? Or a relevant research direction would be great

Comment: @LaRage How long can the numbers be? If you can make them fixed-length integers, you can reduce your memory requirements massively, while keeping searching simple and fast.

Comment: 7 numbers between 700 and 1900

Comment: @LaRage Okay, that means you only need 11 bits per number. So without trying anything real fancy, you can reduce the maximum storage per string from 78ish bytes to just 10 bytes, and you can easily pack this into a struct, so you can avoid the references as well. Making a decent hash for a 10 byte number isn't hard (google will help), and you could probably ignore caching the hash as well. Or, if you prefer even simpler manipulation, just store each number as a `short`, for a total of 14 bytes per string (still almost 90% reduction in size) which avoids bit packing madness :)